# Does the phrase 'tongue bath' have sexual connotations when used to refer to sycophantic behavior?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

When I first heard this phrase as a teenager (late 90s/early 2000s), it was being used to describe sycophantic talk or fulsome praise of someone. At the time, I figured the phrase originated as a comparison with the way a dog might lick its master profusely when it is scared or wants something. I haven't used this phrase in a long time, and recently, I used it. I suppose it's an unfortunate consequence of living in a hypersexualized era, but a while after the conversation, I got to wondering if I should have used that phrase (I was talking to someone older, whom I respect), because it might have a connotation that is quite different from what I originally thought.

**Edit:** Prompted by Jason Bassford, here is a relatively recent example used by a well-known online publication, *[The Huffington Post](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/sean-hannity-questions-trump_us_57b5c1b2e4b034dc7325e0fe)*:

> All The Hard-Hitting Questions Sean Hannity Asked Donald Trump At A ‘Town Hall’ This Week - In which we watch a televised tongue bath so you don’t have to.

**Among mature, educated speakers, does this phrase have any vulgar or sexual connotations?**

Comment: It didn't until you suggested it. ;) I've always thought of the phrase as describing a cat cleaning itself. (I've never heard it used to refer to anything else.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Well, before I posted the question, I googled the phrase, and several of the top results indicated it does. The problem was, these were rather low-quality (even if popular) sites, so I posted this question here, because it's a serious place with serious people. My question has been downvoted, and that's fine except I really can't think of a good reason for it; it only concerns me because I don't want to run afoul of the community here in the future.

Comment: Speaking as a mature, educated speaker - the expression is not one that I would, personally, ever use, in any context that I can possibly think of.

Comment: @NigelJ Fair enough, but why exactly?

Comment: I don't know that I've ever heard the term, other than to describe a cat's actions.

Comment: Seriously, what else could it mean other than sexual connotations when used to refer to sycophantic behaviour?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I think I mentioned that in the OP.

Comment: I think you didn't. You did use the word "sexual" and you did ask whether the phrase had sexual connotations. Are they not very different - in fact, almost opposite - from asking what else it could mean?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin From my OP: "At the time, I figured the phrase originated as a comparison with the way a dog might lick its master profusely when it is scared or wants something. " And after I first heard the phrase (to mean sycophantic behavior), I really only ever heard it to refer to what a dog does to someone it loves.

Comment: Thanks and were you asking about dogs, or people?

Comment: But consider: the term “brown-nose” is obviously based on an intimate, physical act between two people, but it is now used in a euphemistic way that doesn’t *directly* invoke the vulgar etymology/imagery — … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) ...  it is defined as “curry favor with (someone) by acting in an obsequious way”  ([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/brown-nose), see also [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brown-nose)) and “to try too hard to please someone, especially someone in a position of authority, in a way that other people find unpleasant”  ([Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brown-nose), see also [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/brown-nose)).

Comment: @Scott Thank you for that reference, I really appreciate it. Also, great comparison with brown-nose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression [tongue bath](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/tongue_bath) does have a sexual connotation, (an obvious one, IMO:)

> ***A sexual licking of another's body.***
>
> - 2005, Jack Rinella, Becoming a Slave: The Theory and Practice of Voluntary Servitude, Rinella Editorial Services.
> - *If you try giving or receiving a tongue bath, you will notice that it seldom gets completed.*
>
> ***Sycophantic praise:***
>
> 2017: "Donald Trump Tweets About His “Enormously Consensual Presidency" by Matthew Dessem, Slate.
>
> - *It’s possible that Trump meant to include the URL of Goodwin’s tongue-bath of an article instead of his email address.*

Wiktionary